# Created A Mess Trying to Change OSX PHP Version

Tags: macos, terminal, php

So, in a bit of a mess here. I was ***TRYING*** to change the version of my El Capitan PHP version (5.6.2) to PHP7, however I made a bit of a mess.

Now I just want to send things back to normal.

When I run `which php`, I get this:

```
/usr/local/php7/bin/php

which should be default:
/usr/bin/php
```

When I run `php -v`, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libtidy-0.99.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I did quite a few things, wrongly. Starting with wrong paths. This started the mess (STUPID). Note, folder php7 didn't exist...

```
 sudo mv /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php7
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/php7/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
 export PATH=/usr/local/php7/bin:$PATH
```

How can I get thing back to their default state?

Comment: Do you have time machine configured? You could use that to jump back to a previous time. I'm rather new to Mac's but I'm unsure if it would hurt if you just blew away that folder that is wrong and then reinstall again and then fix your path when you're done. If you get back to a stable point, you could also install PHP with Homebrew.

Comment: Can't restore `/usr/`

Comment: `“usr” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X.`

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1554890?tstart=0 or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/how-do-i-undo-overwriting-my-usr-local-bin-folder

Comment: My files aren't hidden. I need to restore `/usr/bin`. I still can't even restore `/usr/local/`

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to restore `/usr/local/bin`. But still getting same issue as originally posted.

Comment: Now, I just need to point `/usr/local/bin/php` back to the default `/usr/bin/php`. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I assume making a link to `/usr/bin/php` would do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

your mac's preinstalled php version still must be 5.6 which i guess should be under

`/usr/bin/php`

---

Just follow these simple steps and u'll be back to normal:

1. Within the Terminal, run `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

`export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Hit `ESC`, Type `:wq`, and hit `Enter`

3. In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

---

you might wanna check this links :

[clean reinstall](http://php-osx.liip.ch/#reinstall)

[changing the path of php](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)